# error with tomcat-requested resource not found- while implementing SSL in Netbeans

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, netbeans, resources

i am trying to implement SSL in my web project. I created the keystore and made the necessary changes in the server.xml of tomcat. the ssl connection works fine when i am testing it by running the apache homepage.
next, i tried to implement this in my web project. i made the necessary changes to the web.xml. now, when i run the app, i get an error saying that "requested resource() is not found".
when i change the  tag from CONFIDENTIAL to NONE, the app works fine, but not when set to CONFIDENTIAL.
Please help me out. I wonder what am i missing !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and made the necessary changes in the server.xml of tomcat.

If run your web app from Netbeans check the `server.xml` of the Tomcat server displayed in the `Service` panel, because Netbeans installs Tomcat and configure a "catalina base" different from "catalina home".

So you might have changed the "catalina home" `server.xml` but not the "catalina base" `server.xml` actually used by Netbeans.